# Multiline if condition in django templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates

My if statement in django template is too long. I want to break that into multiple lines.

```
    {% if ABCDEFGH == BENDHSS and asdasd == asdasdas or asasdas == asdasdd and dasdasdsa == asdasdass or ghgfgsd == efdscsdfg and sgrtvsd == acsdfer %}
```

I want to break the above line of code into multiple lines. 
In python, We break it with a backward slash("\").

```
    if ABCDEFGH == BENDHSS and asdasd == asdasdas or \
        asasdas == asdasdd and dasdasdsa == asdasdass or \
        ghgfgsd == efdscsdfg and sgrtvsd == acsdfer:
```

Could anyone let me know how we do it in django?

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately you can not. Instead of using those long names you can do this

```
{% with a as ABCDEFGH %}
{% with b as BENDHSS %}
{% with c as asdasdas %}
.
.
.
.

   {% if a == b and asdasd == c or asasdas == asdasdd and dasdasdsa == asdasdass or ghgfgsd == efdscsdfg and sgrtvsd == acsdfer %}

{% endwith %}
{% endwith %}
{% endwith %}
```

This workaround is good enough if you want to fly underthe linters radar.

---

Or you can pass those vars in a list  and iterate over them

Answer (score 2):

You can not split that expression in the `if` tag, but you can assign the expression, in your python code, to a new variable and instead pass that to template. e.g.

```
new_var = ABCDEFGH == BENDHSS and asdasd == asdasdas or \
          asasdas == asdasdd and dasdasdsa == asdasdass or \
          ghgfgsd == efdscsdfg and sgrtvsd == acsdfer:
```

and then pass `new_var` to the template.